# It shows the 'undefined reference to clock_gettime' when I build the Android source

Tags: android, ubuntu, build

```
out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/utils.o: 
Infunction `art::InitTimeSpec(bool, int, long long, int, timespec*)':
/tmp/android-src/art/runtime/utils.cc:190: undefined reference to 
`clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I use ubuntu 12.04 and android 4.4.2.

How to fix it?